# Magento - Remove "ShortDescription" Div on 1.8

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.8

A Magento & php noob here. I'm trying to removed the Short Descriptions from a store as they are unnecessary/unneeded. I've adjusted the attributes to disable them.

It seems to leave a white space similar to a 
 although i can't find any in the code.

I've been trawling google and forums but all the fixes are for older outdated version and do not work.

I've tried to removed the nl2br tag but still it has no effect.

Current website is here: www.petwholesale.co.uk/magento/

Is there anyway to force the div not to load? I'm fairly new to all this and it's rather confusing!

Thanks,
Max

Comment: If you can adjust the CSS style for that particular div, have you tried adding "display:none" to the div/class? In the future, it's always helpful to know the things you have already tried.

Comment: Get `Firebug`, inspect the `<li>` element for each product, it's currently got a bottom padding of `60px`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Managed to fix it by changing the padding as pointed out by Nick R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a large amount of padding on the bottom of the list item. The following css section is the area that should be reduced.

```
.col2-left-layout .products-grid li.item, .col2-right-layout .products-grid li.item {
    padding: 0px 20px 60px 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

But even then the reason that the `Add to cart` button appears to display after this padding is because of the position absolute on the action div.

```
.products-grid .actions {
    position: absolute;
}
```